# How to interpret these regression values?

Tags: regression

If GPA(gpa after fall semester in college) is the dependent variable and SAT (score on the SAT) is the independent variable and I have the following parameter estimates:

Intercept: .66306

SAT: .00193

Than would I assume that every additional point a student received on their SAT score would increase the gpa after the fall semester by .00193. So for every addition 100, gpa would increase by .193?

Answer (score 0):

That's what it means, but one should remember that (1) these are *estimated* average GPAs, and (2) one would expect that there's a lot of variability in GPAs beyond what is "explained" by differences in SAT scores; just how much unexplained variability remains is something that would be found in any statistician's report on something like this, and you haven't included that information in your posting; and (3) there may well be more to glean from the data than all this, but we don't have the data before us.